# If A/B gives __ of 3, then B must be at least 4

Tags: linear-algebra, factoring, gre-exam

I had an old note that I quickly wrote and I'm really unable to read the word after 'gives'. Can someone help me out?

"If A/B gives __ of 3, then B must be at least 4"

Comment: Ok, I'll guess:  "a remainder".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word is likely "remainder." The remainder after a division is always less than the divisor, in this case, $B$. This assumes some abuse of notation and the assumption that $B>0$.

The long form would be:

> Given $B$ a positive integer, if the remainder after dividing $A$ by $B$ is $3$, then $B\geq 3+1=4$.